# How to select specific records from a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to pull these information from a table that I created. P_DESCRIPT, P_INDATE,P_PRICE, V_CODE with vendor code 21344 from my PRODUCTS table, but I am getting an error message. Below is my script and error messages. I also attached a photo of the table. Any advice?

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT

SELECT P_DESCRIPT, P_INDATE,P_PRICE, V_CODE
WHERE V_CODE= 21344
```

[image]

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -

SELECT * FROM PRODUCT

SELECT P_DESCRIPT, P_INDATE,P_PRICE, V_CODE
WHERE V_CODE= 21344
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: You need to add semicolon ";" or select the entire query and then execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may select all like this :

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT;
```

To select only the vendor code 21344, just ask :

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE V_CODE = 21344;
```